# Does Apple still monitor or track after having a customer support screen sharing service with ara.apple.com?

Tags: macos, security, macbook, screen-sharing

Is having screen sharing service with ara.apple.com safe?

I had screensharing service with ara.apple.com(https://ara-prn.apple.com/) which is official apple website for apple products support. And they wanted me to install an app after entering session key and they said the app will self-destruct once support session ended.

Would there be a possibility that Apple can still track and monitor that computer even after the support session ended and even if they claim that installment of the app for screen sharing self-destruct?

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell when installing an app if it's adding some extra script or not (as far as I know).

What you can do is check what files that app is accessing (reading/writing).
Check this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/how-to-monitor-file-access-for-an-os-x-application

Also, you can monitor the network traffic and see where that app is connecting to. Check if you can find something on Network Utility. Personally I suggest [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).
With Wireshark you can log the host/ip the app is connecting too, and then after you are done and deleted the app as well, you can monitor if there's still a connection to that host/ip. However, using wireshark is a bit challenging if you don't have networking knowledge.

I'm not sure how that app works exactly, but am assuming it connects to a specific port, and that port should close the moment you don't have the app. But if you're really paranoid, you can try the above.

Comment: I just opened Network in Instruments and clicked "Start an immediate mode recording" and there are quite number of lists below "Network Connectons > Summary: By Process", So how do you know which one that's sending is suspicious? Does this Network from Instruments show all the network including hidden ones that's sending in and out of this computer, or has some limit so have to learn and use Wireshark to detect the full lists of network that's sending in and out for full disclosure of this computer?

Comment: There are no suspicious or hidden connections. I'm not sure what your ISP does with suspicious connections. A connection can be marked as suspicious if its doing a lot of requests. This sometimes is blocked from the ISP, sometimes within your wifi router/modem, and sometimes no action is taken. When no action is taken, it means you'll have to deal with configuring your own firewall. As for hidden networks, if you're recording network connections, it should record everything, not only some of the connections.

Comment: Check this for advanced network debugging: https://www.agnosticdev.com/blog-entry/networking-swift/advanced-network-debugging-xcode  


As for Wireshark, there are no limitations. Wireshark will record all connections, however you'll have to manually track down which process is connecting to an external IP.

Comment: I see. How abut re-installing the MacOS. I re-installed the fresh MacOS after the day I had screen sharing service with Apple(https://ara-prn.apple.com). Would this even have erased the screen sharing app, Or could it have persisted to exist even after re-installing MacOS?

Comment: By reinstalling MacOS you're resetting to a specific version of the OS. When that happens some scrips run on the background, and there's no way to tell if there's some exclusion for that app. I wouldn't worry too much though, as in most of the cases reinstalling a system means resetting everything to its original state, including apps & configs, as well as firewall rules.